# "Оттого" или "от того"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как писать правильно: "оттого" или "от того"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все зависит от контекста. Если слово "оттого" употреблено в значении причины и его можно заметить на "по причине" или "потому что", "поэтому" то пишется слитно.
Пример: "Голова болит оттого, что не выспался".
Если же далее идет определяемое слово, то пишется раздельно.
Пример: *"Пять шагов на север от того дуба"*.