# Оттого/от того, неважно/не важно и тире перед "не"

Tags: пунктуация, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно пишется в приведённых ниже случаях:

1. Тяжело удержать себя от того, чтобы не... (сделать что-то).

Вопрос: "от того" или "оттого"?

2. У всех нас была компания. Дворовая ли, школьная ли, университетская ли – не важно.

Как здесь будет правильно: "не важно" или "неважно"? Насколько уместно тире?

Comment: Скорее всего это ваше Домашнее задание и нехорошо перекладывать его на другие плечи, не прилагая своих усилий. В следующий раз предлагайте варианты решения. Так будет правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Тяжело удержать себя (от чего?) от того, чтобы не (см. 
   ["Оттого" или "от того"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/210/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be))
2. Ваш вариант корректен (см. ["Это неважно" или "Это не важно"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46006/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be))

Comment: Спасибо! Засомневался в правильности своих выводов и решил проверить наверняка. Эти темы я смотрел.