# Оттого или от того?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые, слитно-раздельно, союзы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном примере следует употребить "оттого" или "от того"? И нужна ли запятая перед "что"? Пример:

> ...Маша сообщила родным о замужестве. В слезах оказались все трое: Катя - от радости за старшую сестру, мама - (от)того (,) что дочь так быстро повзрослела и, собственно, сама Маша от переполнявших ее чувств.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Ответ на  ваш вопрос здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/210/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be

Comment: А также и здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445757/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"...Маша сообщила родным о замужестве. В слезах оказались все трое: Катя - от радости за старшую сестру, мама - (от)того (,) что дочь так быстро повзрослела и, собственно, сама Маша от переполнявших ее чувств".*

Если б **оттого** было в другом контексте, я бы написала слитно: *Мама плакала (почему?)оттого (потому), что дочь так быстро повзрослела.*

Но у нас параллельные конструкции - одинаково построенные, поэтому везде плакала от чего? - Катя от радости, мама от того, что дочь ..., Маша от переполнявших её чувств.

Comment: (+1), но, по-моему, нужна запятая после "повзрослела".

Comment: И, возможно, тире между "Маша" и "от".

Comment: Согласна, скопировала, не вчитываясь. Ответила только на вопрос, ошибки не смотрела - "теряю хватку". Обычно куда прихожу - ошибки сразу бросаются в глаза, даже неудобно перед людьми, я ж всё вслух говорю.

Comment: Людмила, slava1947, большое вам спасибо за ответы. Значит, верный вариант: "...Маша сообщила родным о замужестве. В слезах оказались все трое: Катя - от радости за старшую сестру, мама - от того, что дочь так быстро повзрослела, и, собственно, сама Маша - от переполнявших ее чувств". У меня порой возникает путаница с постановкой запятой перед союзом И. Так и сейчас. Объясните, пожалуйста, если не затруднит, почему в данном случае нужна запятая.

Answer (score 2):

**Объяснение запятой перед союзом И**

В слезах оказались все трое: Катя – от радости за старшую сестру, мама – от того,  **что дочь так быстро повзрослела**, и, собственно, сама Маша – от переполнявших ее чувств.

Основная структура предложения: **В слезах оказались все трое: Катя, мама  и сама Маша.**

К каждому члену однородного ряда относится **пояснительный оборот** со значением причины, обособленный с помощью тире, но при этом **второй оборот имеет сложное строение:** указательное слово ***от того*** и обособленное придаточное предложение ***что дочь так быстро повзрослела.***

***Собственно*** – обособленное вводное слово.

Comment: Спасибо вам за подробное разъяснение!